# Java: How do i determine whether a local class defined in an initializer block requires an enclosing instance for instantiation?

Tags: java, class, reflection, static

Right now I'm implementing a method that has one parameter of the type Class and this method returns a boolean if the given class object requires an instance of it's enclosing class for it to be instantiated.

This method currently works as follows:

```
    if (clazz.getEnclosingClass() == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (clazz.isAnonymousClass() || clazz.isMemberClass()) {
        return !Modifier.isStatic(clazz.getModifiers());
    }
    if (clazz.getEnclosingConstructor() != null) {
        return true;
    }
    final Method enclosingMethod = clazz.getEnclosingMethod();
    if (enclosingMethod != null) {
        return !Modifier.isStatic(enclosingMethod.getModifiers());
    }
```

To explain why it is designed as such:

1. It first checks if it's a top-level class, if so, the algorithm can safely return false
2. If the class is anonymous or a member class, it requires a closing instance if it's not static (an anynmous class is automatically static if it's declared in a static constructor/method/initializer-block)
3. The class can now be assumed to be a local class (disregarding arrays and primitives), so it's defined in either a constructor, method or initializer. However, unlike an anonymous class, a local class is never considered static, but still requires an enclosing instance if the local class is defined in a non-static block.
4. A constructor is never static, so in that case return true
5. If it's defined in a method, return true if the method isn't static

I need step 6 to determine whether the local class resides in either a Static Initializer Block or an Instance Initializer Block, so I'm done with the implementation for this function.

So here's where the reflection API falls a bit short. There's no method `Class.getEnclosingInitializer()` or such, nor is there a class that represents an initializer in the reflection package.

Isn't an initializer block a member of a class? In the java 1.8 spec the Member interface only has the implementation classes Field, Executable (with subclasses Constructor and Method), and then there's MemberName that's out of the scope for most users of reflection.

I'm not really sure if the people behind the spec forgot about this situation and local classes actually should be static if declared in a static method/initializer (like anonymous classes). But it seems to me that it's lacking this last bit of consistency from this point of view.

So does anybody have an idea on how to ascertain in which type of initializer block the local class is declared?

I'm not really keen on digging through fields for a synthetic one of a type that equals it's enclosing class, or looping through it's constructors for something akin to that (sidenote: Parameter objects from `Constructor.getParameters()` always return false on `isImplicit()` and `isSynthetic()` no matter what i try... that just seems wrong). So if I can avoid such solutions that would be great.

Comment: looks more like a discussion rather than question.

Comment: Well, i need a way to determine X, and using method Y is something I wish to avoid, so my question is "what is method Z for determining X that I am unaware of?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An interesting puzzle, but I'm afraid it has no solution that satisfies your requirements. Once the source files are compiled into bytecode, the details about class enclosing scope is lost. Remember that JVM is not only for Java language, while the described problem is mostly language-specific.

---

> I need step 6 to determine whether the local class resides in either a
>   Static Initializer Block or an Instance Initializer Block

No such information is available in run-time. Class file has `EnclosingMethod` attribute for local or anonymous classes ([JVMS §4.7.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.7)). However, there is no way to distinguish between enclosing instance initializer and static initializer. The spec explicitly says that

*«method_index must be zero if the current class was immediately enclosed in source code by an instance initializer, static initializer, instance variable initializer, or class variable initializer»*.

Consider these two cases:

```
class Outer {
    {
        // Local class inside instance initializer
        class Local {}
    }
}
```

vs.

```
class Outer {
    static {
        // Local class inside static initializer
        class Local {
            final Outer this$0;

            Local(Outer outer) {
                this$0 = outer;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

They are compiled to almost the same class file. The only difference is that field `this$0` has `SYNTHETIC` flag in the first case, but not in the second. But checking this flag is exactly what you want to avoid. *(Why?)*

---

> local classes actually should be static if declared in a static
>   method/initializer (like anonymous classes)

I would argue that neither local nor anonymous classes should ever be static. Furthermore, Java Language Specification requires them to be non-static:

- *The modifier static pertains only to member classes, not to top level or local or anonymous classes* ([JLS §8.1.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.1)).
- *An anonymous class is always an inner class; it is never static* ([JLS §15.9.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.5)).

So, it's clearly a spec violation that `getModifiers()` sometimes returns `STATIC` for an anonymous class. There is a bug [JDK-8034044](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8034044) that has been fixed in upcoming JDK 9. And that breaks step 2 of your algorithm.

---

Okay, what to do then? It depends on what you actually mean by

> if the given class object requires an instance of it's enclosing class
>   for it to be instantiated

I would say, the above definition implies that all constructors of a class have an extra argument of enclosing class type. In this case there is indeed no way to instantiate a class without an instance of the enclosing class.

However, if you really wish to distinguish between initializer and static initializer, your only chance (as I've shown above) is to look for a field with `SYNTHETIC` flag.

Comment: Regarding not wanting to use the synthetic field for checking: I was unsure of the reliability of using such a method. But it seems my own method up to this point was unreliable to begin with as I had made assumptions based on results rather than the spec, causing me to be dependent on a bug that will be fixed in a future java implementation. Thanks for the detailed explanation and the time you've put into research.

Answer (score 0):

An initializer block isn't something that exists in a compiled class file. Code in static initializer blocks gets put into a static method called `<clinit`>, while code in non-static initializer blocks gets put in every constructor of the class. Therefore, for a local class defined in a non-static initializer block, `getEnclosingConstructor()` should return a non-null value.

Comment: But it returns null in my case though. Might there be something wrong with me IDE? I'm using netbeans 8.1

Comment: Instance initializer block does not belong to any constructor on the language level. Consider a class with multiple constructors - which one will `getEnclosingConstructor()` return?